# Can I give a label same functionality as a table view cell with swipe gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I have a table view controller that is listing list of strings, and another view controller that have a label and in the label im presenting one of the table view cells string.

I want for this label to be able to swipe to mark it done like this:(or 
Maybe have some other ui idea for this)

[image: swipe to mark done]

How can I make it happened?

This is how my view controller with the label looks:

[image]

Tnx

Comment: What have you considered / tried? What did it do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *right= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
     right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    myLabel.userinteractionEnabled = YES;
    [myLabel addGestureRecognizer: right ] ;
}

-(IBAction )swipeRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{

//labelSwiped, do stuff..

}
```

Comment: that is awesome dude! what code do I add in the swipeRight method to move the label 2cm (or x px) to the right? this is what I wanted in the first place :)

Comment: look into CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation()  UIView has a transform property, which is animatable